# Background notification with firebase on database update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want that firebase sends a notification to my app when my database is updated. For example when I write a new entry in this database, the app should receive a notification, even if the app is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Firebase I would suggest you to use the feature `Cloud Messaging`. You can send a `Data Message` and the application knows that the database was updated. Check more info about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options