# Automatic Firebase notifications when the app is killed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications

Is their a way to send automatic Firebase notifications to a specific user based on a change in some parent or child in the Realtime firebase database? I need a way that works even if the app is killed by the user or terminated by the mobile.

Comment: use service to do that `https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html`

Comment: One way would be to keep an active listener in a background service, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40613749). Another (and better) way is to send the notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40191368). These days you'd typically use Cloud Functions for Firebase for that, as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).